# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: prototype is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get every day as DD:MM, this is what I tried:

```
schedule.scheduleJob("55 15 * * *", async function () {
    Number.client.on('error', console.error);
    prototype.padLeft = function (base, chr) {
        var len = (String(base || 10).length - String(this).length) + 1;
        return len > 0 ? new Array(len).join(chr || '0') + this : this;
    }
    const date = new Date,
        dateFormat = [date.getDate().padLeft(), (date.getMonth() + 1).padLeft()].join('-');
```

The error I'm getting is `Cannot read property 'on' of undefined`, if I comment out that line I get: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: prototype is not defined` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, `prototype` is not defined.

Comment: Programming tip #1: Google the error.  Also, a good question description is describing the _error_, not "trying to get date...."

Comment: https://hackernoon.com/prototypes-in-javascript-5bba2990e04b

Comment: There's a lot of incorrect references in your snippet. I would recommend starting over with simpler code that just focuses on the DD:MM formatting first.

Comment: I think you're trying to do `Number.prototype.padLeft = func...`. And like @bradforbes said, There are several other problems in this snippet.

Comment: I think I made a mistake while transferring parts of code, thanks